# Change the root directory to github pages

Tags: github-pages

Create a project with the architecture:

```
| _ Source

| _ Build

  | _index.html
```

Added branch: `git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages`

I put this branch as a source for github pages, but can not find the page on the following link:

```
YourName.github.io/RepoName
```

finds only the following link:

```
YourName.github.io/RepoName/index.html
```

due to incorrect links are not working scripts, styles and images are not loaded.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this and this is how I fixed it: clone into a repository that you create named **USERNAME.github.io** (username is your github account name) and that should do it. Good luck!